# Multiple types of nested properties in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typechecking

I would like to apply types for a variable `something`. `something` can be:

- a string
- an array of string
- a key-value pair: the key is always a string, and the value can be another `something`: either a key-value pair (possibly multiple level nested), a string, or an array of string

Suppose I have a JSON response which matches the structure of the type of `something`:

```
{
  something: {
    fox: 'jump',
    rabbit: {
      bunny: 'carrot',
      alaska: 'hay'
    },
  }
}
```

What I'm doing in TypeScript is:

```
type SomethingType = {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | SomethingType
};

interface SomethingProps {
  something: SomethingType | null
}

class MyApp extends React.Component<SomethingProps> {
  render() {
    const itWorks = this.props.something.fox;
    const itDoesNotWork = this.props.something.rabbit.bunny;
    return ...
  }

  ...
}
```

When my IDE (VS Code) checks the types, for `itWorks` it works. For `itDoesNotWork`, it indicates that its type is `any` and gives the error message below:

```
Property 'bunny' does not exist on type 'string | string[] | SomethingType'.
Property 'bunny' does not exist on type 'string'.
ts(2339)
```

What should I do if want the value of `something.rabbit.bunny`, or even more level nested properties, all have the type of either `string | string[] | SomethingType`?

Comment: Use a type assertion `(something.rabbit as SomethingType).bunny`, add a type guard https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types, ... If at all possible, provide a better type - `(something.fox as SomethingType).bunny` will compile fine but fail at runtime.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much for the suggestion, it works! The type assertion does the magic.

Comment: But it doesn't actually *know*, so if you're wrong you'll get errors later. Hence my suggestion for a better (more specific and accurate) type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks again. I'll look into the code and see how to better apply a more specific and accurate type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding `this` keyword in front of `something` to refer:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component<SomethingProps> {
  itWorks = this.something.fox;
  itDoesNotWork = this.something.rabbit.bunny;
  ...
}
```

Or `this.props`:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component<SomethingProps> {
  itWorks = this.props.something.fox;
  itDoesNotWork = this.props.something.rabbit.bunny;
  ...
}
```

You should also delete the `const` keyword in front of your properties because you are in a class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The previous version of the code was used as an example to describe the issue. The code is updated now. The issue is about the runtime check of the types in TypeScript. You may also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580115/multiple-types-of-nested-properties-in-typescript#comment105326558_59580115 for more information.